# Initiate vibration in an iOS app built using meteor.js

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm building an iOS app using meteor.js - is there anyway to make the device vibrate? I've seen you can do this using just Cordova, but I haven't had any luck finding any information using meteor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this can be accomplished using plugins ([documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#using-cordova-plugins-directly-in-your-application)). You could try [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration) one like this:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-vibration@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration.git/tarball/274003cb331561c3feb42441c117778b25728eb3
```

and then you can use:

```js
// Vibrate for 1 second
// Wait for 1 second
// Vibrate for 3 seconds
// Wait for 1 second
// Vibrate for 5 seconds
navigator.vibrate([1000, 1000, 3000, 1000, 5000]);
```